# unable to load contact photo android

Tags: android, photo, android-contacts

sounds strang but I am unable to load contact photos from android contacts. I have tried alot of code but nothing worked. My manifest is fine, permissions are added. Tired many code including this one from Android.com. It also didn't work:

```
Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.PHOTO_ID },
                    null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    contactId);
            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                    Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(photoUri,new String[] { acts.Photo.PH.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO },
                        null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
 }
        try {
            return getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
            // if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            // if (data != null) {
            // return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            // }
            // }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am testing in Google Nexus 4 with Kitkat. Anyone can help?

Comment: Any exceptions thrown? logcat output?

Comment: inputstream returns null. 
if you use uri for iv.setImageUri(uri) it always say file not found.

Comment: Did you try the solution I've pointed below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, to get the contacts uri. According to this [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI), `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` has been deprecated.

Additionally, check these out:

[Example Code 1](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/)

[Example Code 2](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/android-get-contact-details-id-name-phone-photo/)

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev. It worked, Example 1.
I was using: ContactsContract.Contacts._ID; instead of ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;